# how to run an exe file without using "path" location

Tags: python

I need to run an exe file without using The path location like just using the name of the exe chrome.exe or like that
the user installs the app in a different location

For example, if u want to replace a file the location is different and the app cant continues run the code because u use the path like "c//: and the user install it on "E//:
like I want to run exe file inside exe file.?

is there a way to run the exe from any place?
without adding an environment, because u don't know where the user will install the app

Comment: I think you would have to add the path of the exe to your environment variables if you want to call it from everywhere

Comment: Or try to use the default installation path, and if the exe is not found, let the user enter the correct one.

Comment: You can use `shutil.which` to find the full path to an executable, based on the executable's name https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which

Comment: if u add the path to the environment u need to know the location first, u cant know where the user will install the app, how u can add it then?

Answer (score 0):

Time to learn about the PATH environment variable.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)):

> PATH is an environment variable on Unix-like operating systems, DOS,
> OS/2, and Microsoft Windows, specifying a set of directories where
> executable programs are located.
>
> [...]
>
> When a command is entered in a command shell or a system call is made
> by a program to execute a program, the system first searches the
> current working directory and then searches the path, examining each
> directory from left to right, looking for an executable filename that
> matches the command name given. Executable programs have filename
> extensions of EXE or COM, and batch scripts have extensions of BAT or
> CMD.

So, as long as the directory the executable is in the PATH, you don't need to specify the directory when calling the program.

This, by the way, has nothing to do with python and is simply how the OS locates programs.

Comment: how i can run this without a path? C:\Program Files\QuickCPU the quickGPU app?

Comment: @MortadaNotGenius, you can't. Unless the exe is in the same folder as your script; then you can call it with a relative path. You could use `os.system('C:\Program Files\QuickCPU')` if this points towards an executable

Comment: is in the same folder, when the user installs the app like in c: so if I use just enter the name of the exe can run it? because I don't know where the user will install the app

Comment: Did I stutter? Normally, installing an application will change the system setting for PATH to include the one where the application is installed. Otherwise, you or the user can do it.

Answer (score -2):

So for example, you want to run chrome.exe, you can run it in a terminal by `chrome.exe`

So therefore you can just do

```py
import os

os.system('chrome.exe')
```

I tested this with kate (`os.system('kate')`)

Comment: is there a way to use it in pycharm?

Comment: Does it not work?

Comment: This answer is missing some important information. You need to have the executable in the environment's PATH variable, then you call it without the filetype (`chrome`).

Comment: For chrome and other major browsers they are already in the PATH variable, so you don't need to add them yourself. OP asked how to run chrome, which is already in PATH

Comment: u can run chrome but not other exe, like u, have exe in c: u need to run it using path is there a way to run it by just a name? my folder file inside it exe, I can't run it without path.

Comment: so, for example you have `C:/program/program.exe`, and a python file at something like `C:/program/launcher/main.py`, you could just use relative path and do `../program.exe`

Comment: If it's more complicated than that just use the PATH variable